# RCP4 Window loses its background color when closed and re-opened

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I created this user management application and applied some styling to it. All my windows background colors appear fine when viewed for the first time, but if I close them using the cancel button or otherwise and then re-open them the background color is just gone. I thought that it might be due to the way I close the windows setting the to be rendered to false, but that can't be because the buttons and groups still retain their styling. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it? If I should post any more code please request so. Thanks!

[image][image]

I assign the styling here:

```java
@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct(Composite parent) 
{
    parent.setData("org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.CssClassName", "ColorGrad");

    RoleController roleController = new RoleController();
    parent.getShell().setBounds(0, 0, 380, 435);

    parent.setLayout(null);
    ......
```

The cancel button function if indeed it does somehow have something to do with it:

```java
btnCancel = new Button(parent, SWT.NONE);
btnCancel.setBounds(185, 354, 160, 36);
btnCancel.setText("Cancel");
btnCancel.setData("org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.CssClassName", "orange");
btnCancel.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener( ) {
    public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
    }

    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        modelService.find("ats_usermanagement_rcp.part.UserAddDialog", application).setToBeRendered(false);
        modelService.find("ats_usermanagement_rcp.dialog.UserAdmin", application).setToBeRendered(false);
    }
});
```

CSS:

```css
.ColorGrad
{
    swt-background-mode: default;
    background-color: #697d87 #ff4612 #697d87 #697d87 #ff4612 60% 90% 95% 100%  
}
```

Comment: Is the @PostConstruct being called when the window is reopened?

Comment: I always assumed it is called whenever rendered again

Comment: Don't assume, do some testing and determine if it is called on reopen or not.

Comment: A likely cause of this is setting the CSS style data (and the layout) on the parent composite - that composite does **not** belong to your code and you should not change the layout or set data on it.  Create your own composite as the only child of the parent and set the values on that.

Comment: How does one call the @PostConstruct whenever it is rendered again? Apologies, still new to rcp.

Comment: You can't, it is only called when the class is constructed. In any case it shouldn't be necessary if you set styles on Composites that belong to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

In the Application.e4xmi I have a Window containing a single Part. **Only** the Window has 'to be rendered' turned off.

The handler to show the Window does:

```java
@Execute
public void execute(final EModelService modelService, final MApplication app)
{
  final var window = modelService.find("window-id", app);

  window.setToBeRendered(true);
}
```

The part class has:

```java
@PostConstruct
public void postConstruct(final Composite parent, final EModelService modelService, final MApplication app)
{
  final var comp = new Composite(parent, SWT.None);
  comp.setLayout(new GridLayout());

  comp.setData("org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.CssClassName", "css-class-name");

  final var close = new Button(comp, SWT.PUSH);
  close.setText("Close");
  close.addListener(SWT.Selection, event ->
    {
      final var window = modelService.find(("window-id", app);

      window.setToBeRendered(false);
    });
}
```

This is setting the CSS style on a Composite which is the only child of `parent`.

This code is for Java 10 or later (it uses `var`) it will need small changes for earlier versions of Java.